# TestCafe can&#39;t establish browser connection when running against Electron app

Tags: testing, automated-tests, electron, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am attempting to run a test on our Electron app using TestCafe. I have tried many things but after many hours am still getting the error below:

> "ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser
>   connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device
>   failure."

The cases I have read Googling around do not seem to apply to my case.

I have everything set up as described here: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-electron#testing-an-executable-electron-application

The .testcafe-electron-rc file is correct in that my app does indeed launch but errors as above. I do not think it gets to my script which is very simple for debugging purposes. I have tried changing the mainWindowUrlPath to various locations since it seems like my app is run from C:/Program Files/MyApp/resources/" which contains an app.asar file even though our app is located in "C:/Program Files/MyApp/MyApp.exe"

I  have tried setting up the .testcafe-electron-rc in many configurations including the one described in the documentation as well as many others. An example is below which I realize is non-standard:

```
{
     "mainWindowUrl": "C:/Program Files/MyApp/resources/app.asar/index.html",
     "electronPath":  "C:/Program Files/MyApp/MyApp.exe" 
}
```

Note, I have never seen the index.html anywhere in the app directory but assume that TestCafe must dive into the asar in some manner.

I have disabled the Windows firewall but still, the same issue exists.

I have run my tests with nodejs installed globally and testcafe and the Electron provider installed globally and locally (i.e. run these configurations separately) but the same issue occurs.

Does anyone have any other ideas? Any help appreciated.

This is on Windows 10.

m

Comment: Please use `testcafe-browser-provider-electron@0.0.8` and share the full error message. The latest version reports all links that can be used for `mainWindowUrl` in the error message.

Comment: @AndreyBelym are there any additional commandline parameters required? I made sure the testcafe electron provider was updated however I am not seeing any additional messages with the links available as you describe.

Comment: @AndreyBelym FYI I have used the -d switch but still no additional information. I also ran as the link below describes and indeed, as you probably know, it never gets into my script https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/debug-tests/chrome-dev-tools.html

Comment: @AndreyBelym correction, it does get into my script file but gets stuck on the  
    fixture `Electron test`  
    .page('./index.html')

Comment: No additional CLI keys are required. Just wait until TestCafe fails to start a browser and pay attention to the error message. When I don't specify `mainWindowUrl` correctly, I have the following error message: 

`ERROR Was unable to open the browser "electron:" due to error.

Error: The main window page at file:///F:/test/test/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/index.html was not loaded.
Use the mainWindowUrl option to specify one of the following pages as the main window page:

file:///F:/test/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/index.html`

Comment: @AndreyBelym I have tried but do not see this message. I put in a bogus value for mainWindowUrl as well. By using console.log I can see it gets into my test script up to .page and gets stuck there.

Comment: @AndreyBelym does it matter where our app is installed? It is in c:\Program Files\App and is the release version of the application.

Comment: The app installation directory shouldn't affect a test scenario. Could you please update your question with the following information: TestCafe and Electron provider installation paths; a sample Electron public application; all your project (application, packages, tests and other files) directories' location? I want to follow all these steps and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @V.Airich unfortunatley I am not able to make our app public. Is there a way I can install everything locally and debug myself? I have run my tests with node installed globally and I have run the testcafe provider globally and locally but the same issue occurs.

Comment: You can send all necessary details at support@devexpress.com, and only you and TestCafe team can have access to it. This will allow TestCafe team to analyze all the information and find a suitable way to proceed this question faster.

Comment: Addendum, with help from DevExpress, this now works with TestCafe 1.5 and electron-browser-provider 0.0.12.